# How to make it navbar responsive in scss?

Tags: html, sass

Hi i am not getting responsive header here while in tab and mobile how to make it responsive.

Here is the html code

.HTML

```
<header>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="./assets/images/logo1.png" alt="cstep" class="img1" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="./assets/images/logo2.png" alt="caps" class="img2" /></a>
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" style="z-index: 1;">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
    <nav id="main-nav-wrap" style="z-index: 1;">
        <ul class="main-navigation">
            <li><a href="#intro">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about1">about1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a routerLink='/2019'>2019</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

I want it to be responsive in scss any help will be thankful.

Comment: Do you have any CSS code already?

Answer (score 0):

You could use media queries to achieve this.

For example:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 200px) {
  /* change content here */
}
```

W3 Schools also has good documentation on how to do this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

**Hello, Please Follow steps by your own code style.**

```css
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  min-height: $navbar-height; // Ensure a navbar always shows (e.g., without a .navbar-brand in collapsed mode)
  margin-bottom: $navbar-margin-bottom;
  border: 1px solid transparent;

  // Prevent floats from breaking the navbar
  @include clearfix;

  @media (min-width: $grid-float-breakpoint) {
    border-radius: $navbar-border-radius;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers but nothing seems to workout as when we see the page in mobile view that toggle button is not working.